# How to install AV on existing Azure VM using agent tools?

Tags: powershell, azure, cloud, anti-virus

If I already deployed a VM, how can I use the VM agent to install an antivirus software from the Azure marketplace (i.e. McAfee)? There must be some Powershell command or something but everything I've tried hasn't worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**From Preview Portal**:

Browse -> Virtual Machines -> Select VM -> All Settings -> Extensions -> Add -> Select Extension -> Create.

**Using Powershell**:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn606311.aspx

Each extension has different pre-requisites so it's not only a matter of installing the extension using powershell commands. Check the above list for instructions for each one.

**Guide for Mcaffee**

http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/12/01/new-antimalware-options-for-protecting-azure-virtual-machines/

Create this file under c:\mcafee.config. This config is for a trial account. If you have a subscription check the above link.

```
{
    "featureVS": "true",
    "featureBP": "true",
    "featureFW": "true",
    "relayServer": "false"
}
```

Execute on powershell:

```
# Get the VM
$vm = Get-AzureVM –ServiceName $servicename –Name $name

# Add McAfee Endpoint Protection to the Virtual Machine
Set-AzureVMExtension -Publisher McAfee.EndpointSecurity -ExtensionName McAfeeEndpointSecurity -Version 6.* -VM $vm.VM -PublicConfigPath c:\mcafee.config

# Update the VM which will install the McAfee Endpoint Protection Agent
Update-AzureVM -Name $servicename -ServiceName $name -VM $vm.VM
```